# How to write css class selector in scss

Tags: css, sass

I want to write the below code for a scss like **[class*="col-"]** this one. i know how to write it in css but m using scss now.

My css code is here

```
@media only screen and (min-width : 768px) {
    .is-table-row {
        display: table;
    }
    .is-table-row [class*="col-"] {
        float: none;
        display: table-cell;
        vertical-align: top;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
@media only screen and (min-width : 768px) {
    .is-table-row {
        display: table;

       [class*="col-"] {
           float: none;
           display: table-cell;
           vertical-align: top;
     }
}
```

It has a some output as your css.